# smd resistor and regular through hole resistor

Tags: led, pcb, resistors, diodes, surface-mount

My question is fairly simple. I am building an SMD LED board and i am limited in space. So originally i was planning on going with through hole resistors, but have it being i'm very limited on space i'm looking at the option of going the smd resistor route.

Essentially what i need is a 68 ohm 1/4 w through resistor but i want to use an smd resistor. When i type in 68 ohm 1/4 smd in ebay it showed me the 1206 SMD type (here's the link) http://www.ebay.com/itm/50-Value-1206-SMD-Resistor-Kit-0R-10MR-5-5000pcs-/330655035675?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4cfc93711b
*i then got excited and realized that a 68 ohm SMD might not be the same as a 68 ohm 1/4w through hole resistor, so what would be the equivalent to the through hole resistor in a smd resistor type

It has all the ones i require but i want to be sure i'm buying the correct ones.
Again i apologize for the such noob question but i want to be sure i buy the correct one before i burn out my LED.

and on a side note. i use an LED calculator (link) http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz

Do you guys think it gives the correct values for and SMD LED as well. Any suggestions i will happily take. I like learning the correct way of all things i've been doing bad.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why would you look for your components on ebay?

Comment: The cheapest ones i can find. I know i wasn't too happy with posting the word ebay on here..

Comment: If you can spare the board space, a double-sided copper pour with vias directly under the resistor body can act as a heat sink providing more engineering for your circuit.

Comment: @fgmoren312: hard to tell without knowing how much you want and if you can use the other ones from that package (btw. I do not like having just a bag of loose smd components, at least a cut reel it should be), and this is really not the right site to discuss shopping things, but you should be able to find that resistor for 4-5c in low, and 0.2-0.5c in larger quantities.

Comment: Oh, hell yeah, don't buy loose baggies of SMD resistors, ever. The reel (or partial reel) is worth paying for. And you can get [a 5k reel of Panasonic resistors](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ERJ-8GEYJ680V/P68ETR-ND/1930) for $23.

Comment: As a point of interest, I decided to test the "LED circuit suggester", it seems to work quite okay for what I threw at it. Good thing to use if you don't know the maths yourself yet, but try to get to understanding how that all works. Many "conceptual" and real questions to be had here on the subject of resistors and the like.

Comment: Buying some cheap parts from eBay for a one off hobby project or maybe prototype is okay, just not for production unless your okay with risk. And as a point, almost all ebay smd parts come in 25 to 50 count cut tape, not loose loose.

Answer (score 3):

Resistance is resistance; there is no difference between using a 68ohm TH resistor, a 68ohm SMD resistor, or a 68ohm carbonized strand of cotton, *assuming resistance is the only criterion you care about*. It isn't, but you've already handled power dissipation by specifying a certain amount and finding an appropriate SMD resistor.

Answer (score 2):

The eBay listing for the 1206 packages clearly lists them as being 1/4 watt:

> This is an assorted kit of 5000 components as listed below. They are
>   all bagged and labeled, are all 1206 size. The tolerance is 5% 1/4 W .
>   100 components of each value.

1/4 W SMT is the same as 1/4 W through-hole as for as power dissipation even though they are physically smaller.